# How to create a json object from two arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json

I have the following arrays

```
['a','b','c','d','e','f']

[1762, 770, 93, 474, 323, 351]
```

I would like to convert them into a list of json objects so that I end up with an object that looks a bit like this

```
{
  "SomeObject": [
    {
      "name": "a",
      "value": 1762
    },
    {
      "name": "b",
      "value": 770
    },
    {
      "name": "c",
      "value": 93
    },
    {
      "name": "d",
      "value": 474
    },
    {
      "name": "e",
      "value": 323
    },
    {
      "name": "f",
      "value": 351
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I concert these arrays to the above object in JavaScript.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const keys = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
const values = [1762, 770, 93, 474, 323, 351];

const result = keys.map((key, i) => ({ name: key, value: values[i] }));

console.log(result);
```